# How to get all of the names from a specific Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a portfolio filtering for categories in order to show works from each category.

It works with a `data-filter` that triggers the works like this:

```
<span class="filter" data-filter=".<%= c.name.downcase.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '') %>"><%= c.name %></span>
```

That works correctly for separate categories, but I want the `:active` tab to contain all of the works, so I need to get ALL of the category names:

```
<span class="filter active" data-filter="<%= Category.all.map(&:name) %>">Todos</span>
```

How can I retrieve the category names like "name1 name2 name3"...?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Category.group(:name).pluck(:name).join(' ')` => `Category.group(:name).pluck(:name)` will return an array of the different unique names existing in your DB (no duplicates). Then `join(' ')` will just call `to_s` on each array's element and then `join` them with a white space.

Comment: Your view should just display the information, it should not retrieve it. That's what controllers are for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the value of the `name` attribute for each category do this:

```
Category.pluck(:name) #=> ['name1', 'name2',..., 'name10']
```

From what you wrote you'd like the names to be spaced out like this "name1 name2 name3". Then just join the names with a space between each of them:

```
Category.pluck(:name).join(' ') #=> name1 name2 ... name10
```

@Stefan makes a valid point. It is considered bad practice to have logic such as `Category.all` in the view layer. Rather, you should put that logic in your controller action that is responsible for rendering the particular template (view).

i.e:

*in controller*

```
def works
 @category_names = Category.pluck(:name)
end
```

*in view*

```
<span class="filter active" data-filter="<%= @category_names.join(' ') %>">Todos</span>
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but I'd put the `.join(' ')` part into the view.

Comment: @Stefan agreed :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Category.all` loads in every single category as a fully fleshed out model. Calling `Category.all.map(&:name)` takes those models cherry-picks one little thing, and throws the rest in the garbage. `pluck` side-steps all of this and can be orders of magnitude more efficient because of it.

Comment: Yes. Basically, pluck will make the query by selecting specific column(s) and will only that much in memory. `SELECT name from categories`. The overhead of loading all fields is massive when you have big table or lot of columns.

Comment: It's not just the additional fields, `pluck` doesn't instantiate the models.